# String was not recognizes as a valid Datetime

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

Im trying to display my user's birthday into like this "January 1, 1990" -"MMMM dd,yyyy"
from my database

and my data type in my database is DateTime and has a format like this "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

But whenever i tried to display it. it gets an error "String was not recognizes as a valid Datetime"

```
  Try
        con.Open()
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, last_name + ', ' + first_name + ' ' + middle_name as name, course, section, position, address, birthday from Users"
        comm.Connection = con
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader
        While (dr.Read())
            Dim mydate = (dr("birthday"))
            Dim edate As Date = Date.ParseExact(mydate, "MMMM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
            With ListView1.Items.Add(dr("user_id"))
                .subItems.Add(dr("name"))
                .subItems.Add(dr("course"))
                .subItems.Add(dr("section"))
                .subItems.Add(dr("position"))
                .subItems.Add(dr("address"))
                .subItems.Add(edate)
            End With
        End While
        comm.Dispose()
        dr.Close()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: A `Datetime` has no format, neither in .NET nor in the database. Also, i don't understand why you use `MMMM/dd/yyyy` to parse a string that has this format: `MMMM dd,yyyy`(as you've mentioned).

Comment: a want to format it do display it in my table like this "January 1, 1993"

because in default if i display it directly from my database.. it displays something like this "1993-01-01 00:00:00.000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this format 'January 1,1993'...Try this...

```
Try
    con.Open()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, last_name + ', ' + first_name + ' ' + middle_name as name, course, section, position, address, birthday from Users"
    comm.Connection = con
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.Read())
        Dim mydate = (dr("birthday"))
        Dim edate As Date = mydate
        With ListView1.Items.Add(dr("user_id"))
            .subItems.Add(dr("name"))
            .subItems.Add(dr("course"))
            .subItems.Add(dr("section"))
            .subItems.Add(dr("position"))
            .subItems.Add(dr("address"))
            .subItems.Add(Format(edate, "MMMM d,yyyy"))
        End With
    End While
    comm.Dispose()
    dr.Close()
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: @BLitE.exe, Happy to help :) If it answered your problem, I'd appreciate it if you marked my post as answered :) Thanks.

Comment: yeah.. right now im just a student tryong to learn the basics of programming.. i find this site most useful in everything.. thanks to all of you guys.. that give their precious time to help other programmers out there.. :)